# Parallelize processing of a huge list

Tags: python, multithreading, list

I need to do a lot of webscraping from domains stored in a .txt file (about 50 MB size).

I want to do it multi-threaded. Hence I am loading a number of entries into a Python list and process each with threads.

Example:

```
biglist = ['google.com','facebook.com','apple.com']
threads = [threading.Thread(target=fetch_url, args=(chuck,)) 
           for domain in biglist]
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

It works but it seems to me that it's not very efficient, as there is a lot of memory usage and it takes a lot of time to complete.

What better ways are there to achieve what I'm doing?

Comment: That's a lot of threads at a time. Use realistic chunck size ( `< 2*cpu` ) or a thread pool

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong library. `threading.Thread` does not really benefit from multiple processors as it is blocked by the [*Global Interpreter Lock*](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock).

From the documentation of the `threading` module ([c.f.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)):

> **CPython implementation detail:** In CPython, due to the *Global Interpreter Lock*, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use `multiprocessing`. However, `threading` is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.

I suggest you to use a [process pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) from the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#) module and [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) to compute the results in parallel. It doesn't make sense to use more processes than you have processors then.

From the documentation of the `multiprocessing` module ([c.f.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)):

> `multiprocessing` is a package that supports spawning processes using an API similar to the `threading` module. The `multiprocessing` package offers both local and remote concurrency, effectively side-stepping the *Global Interpreter Lock* by using subprocesses instead of threads. Due to this, the `multiprocessing` module allows the programmer to fully leverage multiple processors on a given machine. It runs on both Unix and Windows.

Example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

number_of_processors = 3

data = range(10)

def func(x):
    print "processing", x
    return x*x

pool = Pool(number_of_processors)
ret = pool.map(func, data)
```

The output is:

```
$ python test.py
processing 0
processing 1
processing 3
processing 2
processing 4
processing 5
processing 6
processing 7
processing 8
processing 9
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use lists/threads, but a queue/processes instead.
If you know Redis I suggest RQ (http://python-rq.org) - I'm doing the same thing and works quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to moooeeeeps answer.
There is another way of handling lot of connections in one thread, without spawning expensive processes. Gevent has a similar api to multiprocessing/multithreading.

Docs and tutorials:

- http://www.gevent.org/intro.html
- http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/

Also there is a python framework for scraping urls:
http://scrapy.org/

Example from docs asyc/sync fetching urls:
    import gevent.monkey
    gevent.monkey.patch_socket()

```
import gevent
import urllib2
import simplejson as json

def fetch(pid):
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json')
    result = response.read()
    json_result = json.loads(result)
    datetime = json_result['datetime']

    print('Process %s: %s' % (pid, datetime))
    return json_result['datetime']

def synchronous():
    for i in range(1,10):
        fetch(i)

def asynchronous():
    threads = []
    for i in range(1,10):
        threads.append(gevent.spawn(fetch, i))
    gevent.joinall(threads)

print('Synchronous:')
synchronous()

print('Asynchronous:')
asynchronous()
```